# Substring between specific characters in a string multiple times

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, substring

Let's say we have an array of strings:

```
public string[] test = {"(as) (bd) (ct)", "(sdf) te"};
```

I want to be able to substring between the **()** and then add the strings to an array.
No matter how many times the **()** occure in the string I want be able to substring the content between it.

I've tried using string.**Split**()

```
public static void Main()
        {
            //SolvePattern(3, 5, 4);
            foreach (var item in transmissions)
            {
                var test = item.Split('(', ')');
                foreach (var a in test)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                }
            }
        }
```

but that would return the **"te"** aswell, which is not between **()**.

Also worth noting is that the solution should **not** be using **regex**.

Comment: This should be a lot simpler with regex

Comment: What's the reason for not allowing regex?

Comment: It could be a homework question which has arbitrary constraints.

Comment: As @Ibrennan208 said, it's a problem for school!

Comment: Will your data always match the example provided? Or is it possible that you will have to parse a string such as `"test(inside)()12((()"`? Will the parentheses always be a single pair of open and close? or is it possible to have multiple in a row as in my example string?

Comment: Either it is x-amount of letters inside the () or a specific letter outside such as;
**{ "(zyx) bc", "(ert) (ert) (ert)", "(ab) d (dc)" }**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is like that then you could do something like this:

```
string[] test = { "(as) (bd) (ct)", "(sdf) te" };
var result = test.SelectMany(t => t.Split())
              .Where(t => t.StartsWith("(") && t.EndsWith(")"))
              .Select(t => t.Trim(new char[] {'(',')'}));
foreach(var item in result) {
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: An issue with this is that you are relying on a split on whitespace. Although the example shows whitespace, they don't clarify if that is consistent with all of their data sets. The only thing they do specify is that the string should be within parentheses.

Comment: @Ibrennan208, in first sentence I clearly specified "if it is like that". In a real world this would be a job of regex anyway.